# Assigning multiple Customize keyboard shortcut keys for ArcMap

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, arcobjects

I am using ArcMap 10.1 and 10.2.1.

I have attached the below image for reference.  I want to assign multiple Customize keyboard shortcut keys at the same time.

Is it possible do this using ArcPy/Python?

This is to save effort changing the Customize keyboard shortcut keys from my MXD file for other people.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. There is no exposure of the main GUI of ArcMap to the customize dialog  in arcpy.

You can set to save customization to the MXD by ticking this option.

[image: Dialog]

So turn on that option, set up all your short cut keys and save the MXD. Then distribute the MXD to whoever and they will have these key strokes available to them.